# program produces numbers when I expected alpha characters

Tags: c, loops, nested

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char x, y;
  for(x='a';x<='c';++x)
  {
    for(y='a';y<='c';++y)
    {
      printf("%c %d\r\n",x,y);
    }
  }
  return(0);
}
```

I wanted:
a a
a b
a c
b a
b b ... etc

I get:
a 97
a 98
a 99
b 97
b 98 ... etc

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a `%d` inside that `printf`

Comment: @PiRocks No it won't. The `char` value will undergo default argument promotion to `int`. (In fact, both `%d` and `%c` expect an argument of type `int`.)

Comment: @PiRocks — no it won't.  The values in `x` and `y` are promoted to `int` in the call to `printf()` because of the ellipsis `, ...)` at the end of the prototype of `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

This was my first program and first compile. Thanks for responses.
I changed the one line from:

```
printf("%c %d\r\n",x,y);
```

to:

```
printf("%c %c\r\n",x,y);
```

I have a lot to learn :/